# Base64 image decoding issue - empty .png file?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, canvas, base64

I'm trying to get a `.png` image from `<canvas>` element generated basing on `html` code.

The `javascript` i'm using is:

```
function canvityo() {
        html2canvas(document.body, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild( canvas );
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "imgprocess.php",
          data: { 
             imgBase64: dataURL
          }
        }).done(function(o) {
          console.log('saved'); 
        });
  }
});
}
```

I have `html2canvas` library linked, it creates good `<canvas>` (can see them since I used `appendChild`), and now I'd like to convert those `<canvas>` into `photo.png` file, to be able to either save it on server, or `INSERT INTO` as `blob` to my `database table.

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

to this point it seems everything is working fine (I can manage to get this `url`, which appears to be hella long). Because of strange look i'm pretty much sure i'd need to use `base64 decoding` to retrieve it as `image` file.

My `imgprocess.php` looks like that:

```
<?php

$img = $_POST['data'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
$fileName = 'photo.png';
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);

?>
```

It does output `photo.png` file, but the file is `empty` and as I'm not very experienced I've been struggling to find cause of this issue.

Maybe you guys could help me deal with this problem?

Comment: Thanks for the help Damian ;) Coping with it from morning.

Comment: @NeilBannet glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `$img = $_POST['imgBase64'];` not `$img = $_POST['data'];` as your data object's key name is `imgBase64` when sending the ajax post request.

Comment: i knew it wouldbe something silly, thank you @moáois ! Will tick as best answer in a moment that I'd be able to :) works great now!